# Алгоритм построения бинарной структуры

Tags: алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Есть древовидная структура сюжета с многочисленными ответвлениями, зависящими от выбора игрока.
Каждая развилка содержит только два варианта.

Это оформлено в виде строк в таблице базы данных, где для каждой точки указано её название, а так же название обеих точек, в которые может попасть игрок из текущей.

Нужен скрипт для построения ассоциативного массива, где каждая ячейка будет содержать две ячейки соответствующие возможным точкам перехода из данной ячейки.

*Я понимаю, как рекурсивно уйти в глубь, чтоб построить одну ветку такого дерева, я не могу понять, как после этого вернуться к необработанным вариантам*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример префиксного обхода дерева

```
public void PreOrderTraversal(Action action)
{
    PreOrderTraversal(action, _head);
}

private void PreOrderTraversal(Action action, BinaryTreeNode node)
{
    if (node != null)
    {
        action(node.Value);
        PreOrderTraversal(action, node.Left);
        PreOrderTraversal(action, node.Right);
    }
}
```

Параметр Action определяет действие над каждым из узлов.

**UPDATE** 
Не правильно понял Ваш вопрос. Загрузка дерева из XML файла (принцип тот же).

```
public MyTree<string> LoadTree()
{
    MyTree<string>.Node[] NewNode = new MyTree<string>.Node[xNodes.Count];
    for (int i = xNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string self_name = xNodes[i].InnerText;
        string true_id   = xNodes[i].Attributes["true_id"].Value;
        string false_id  = xNodes[i].Attributes["false_id"].Value;

        if (true_id == "null" && false_id == "null")
        {
            NewNode[i] = new MyTree<string>.Node(self_name);
        }
        else
        {
            NewNode[i] = new MyTree<string>.Node(self_name, NewNode[int.Parse(true_id)], NewNode[int.Parse(false_id)]);
        }
    }

    MyTree<string> Tree = new MyTree<string>();
    Tree.Root = NewNode[0];

    return Tree;
}
```

Весь проект можно увидеть в моем [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c5crn2up7m9mmdp/AAAoG9Cxw5ZMyRpeI33E4r4Aa?dl=0)

Comment: Это код, который обходит уже готовое дерево. А мне нужен код, который построит мне дерево по таблице значений.

Comment: Павел, спасибо. Но есть проблема. Код, который вы представили написан на незнакомом мне языке. Если вас не затруднит, добавьте, пожалуйста, комментарии, поясняющие действия. Чувствую, что отгадка в руках, а расшифровать не могу.